# The type or namespace name 'MediaServices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I'm replicating EncodeBlob_SingleOut_Function from [Integrating Azure Media Services with Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/) article. It was running on my local when debugging on Visual Studio 2015. However, when I published the function in Azure Portal, I am getting "The type or namespace name 'MediaServices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" when compiling. Aside from MediaServices class, the Function app in Azure portal can't find also other objects like CloudMediaContext, MediaServicesCredentials, IAsset, IAccessPolicy, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I followed the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/) you provided and created my Azure Function based on the EncodeBlob_SingleOut_Function sample. After some trials, I could make it work as expected on Azure. Here are some possible causes, you could refer to them:

Log into Azure Portal, choose your Function App, click "Function app settings > Go to App Service Editor".

[image]

Make sure the content structure of your Azure Funtion looks like this:

[image]

**Note:** The `project.json` file is under the root directory of your function. The folder `Presets` and `Shared` need to under the root directory of `wwwroot`. You could find them as follows:

[image]

You could upload directory/file via App Service Editor or KUDU.

Upon the configuration without change any code, when a blob is uploaded and you could find the function is triggered  as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Great response Bruce,
Yes, it is something to do with nugget and the package manager.  There appears to be an issue with pulling down the nugget packages in the Project.json file. 
I've noticed this before but have not figured out what is triggering the issue yet.

I'll investigate this some more today to see if I can find why nugget is failing occasionally.

Also note, that i just recently updated the package versions, since there are newer ones available.

```js
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "windowsazure.mediaservices": "3.8.0.3",
        "windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions": "3.8.0.3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```